# How to make PhpStorm understand the type of a Doctrine repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, phpstorm, symfony-3.4

I use Symfony 3.4 with Doctrine and this is how I get one of my repositories:

```
$members = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Member::class)->getAllMembersForClient($client);
```

Developing with PhpStorm, the IDE does not know what the method `getRepository(Member:class)` returns and therefore doesn't offer auto-complete. So it shows me an error for the method call `getAllMembersForClient($client)`

Is there a good way to fix this? How do other Doctrine users handle this problem?

Comment: I thought that Symfony plugin should take care of this ... If not and using intermediate variable for typehinting is not desirable -- try Metadata (it's made for such cases) -- https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Double-check that you've installed the 'Symfony' plugin, as that generally provides the functionality to recognise that `getRepository(Member::class)` would return the repository that is defined by annotations (or other means) to PHPStorm.

You should be able to find it in the menu: Settings> Plugins> {search for 'symfony'}.  If it is not already in the list, 'Browse Repositories...' under the list of plugins.

You have to enable it per project (File> Settings> Languages & Framework> PHP> Symfony) & also install the Php Annotation plugin.

Comment: Thanks Alister - that seems to make a lot of sense. Currently the Php Annotation plugin is shown as not compatible with the current PhpStorm version. So I am looking forward to the fix for that.

Comment: There had been some previous (fairly recent) versions of PHPStorm that were marked as not compatible.  Updates to Storm and the plugin have fixed that and i'm running 2018.2 EAP - released May 17th 2018 and the Symfony plugin, v0.16.165 without any issues.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use temporary variable and typehint:

```
/* @var $membersRepository MemberRepository */
$membersRepository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Member::class);
$members = $membersRepository->getAllMembersForClient($client);
```

Comment: Thanks for the typehint info - I didn't know that yet. Very useful.